# Password Confirmation does not match for Laravel Fortify Registration

Tags: laravel-8, user-registration, laravel-fortify

I am using Fortify for Laravel authentication and I am having an issue with password confirmation when a user is registering.

Fortify creates `Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php` and this is how it looks like after I've added some dumps to debug.

```
public function create(array $input)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique(User::class),
            ],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);

        dump($input);
        dump($input['password'] === $input['confirm_password']);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            dump($validator->errors());
        }
        dd();

        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

[image]

It clearly shows that `password` is identical to `confirm_password` but the validator fails on comparing the two.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove this line:

```
confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
```

2.Rename your confirm password field:

```
 `name = 'password_confirmation'`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The reason the validation fails is this line:

```
'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
```

The `CreateNewUser` class has the trait `PasswordValidationRules` coming from the line here:

```
use PasswordValidationRules;
```

This trait provides the method mentioned earlier (`passwordRules()`). Now if you check the trait (located at App\Actions\Fortify) it has the following line (dafault if you haven't changed it):

```
return [
            'required',
            'string',
            Password::min(8)
                ->letters()
                ->mixedCase()
                ->numbers(),
            'confirmed'
        ];
```

The last item in the array `confirmed` is a validation rule which works by taking the variable it is validating (`password` in this case) and looking for a variable named `password_confirmation`. This is why the above code that you tried doesn't work. You can check out the rule here from the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-confirmed

By the way, your rule

```
'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
```

actually works. It's the `confirmed` rule on the variable `password` that fails. You can see it by the key of the messages array. It's `password` not `confirm_password`.

So, the solution that was provided by @CoderYellow will work. I hope this makes it clear why.